# Antialiasing with compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, antialiasing

Is there any way to apply anti-aliasing to an image in the compositor?  I have a complex compositor setup, and during the compositing, some of the anti-aliasing is lost due to the bilateral blur filter.  Does anyone know of a way to perform antialiasing within the compositor?

Comment: I don't know of any way to create an anti-aliasing filter in the compositor (It might be possible, but I'm not sure it's the best approach). Instead you might want to try and fix whatever is aliasing your image (I.E. find out why the bilateral blur filter is doing this). Could you upload a screenshot or two of the nodesetup/problem?

Comment: try turning full sample on under the render settings > anti aliasing. you will have to render again. not sure if this will work in your case but if it does it will look properly anti-aliased after the render and composite is complete